# is dp/dt = P(1 - 2P^2) a Logistic Differential Equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I currently going through a differential equations course and I am presented with the question:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\D}{d\!}
\text{is } 
\frac{\D p}{\D t} = p(1 - 2p^2)\text{ a logistic DE}?
$$
I tried to solve the DE and plot it to see how it looks and it looks like what any logistic DE looks like. but I was told by some friends that it is not logistic because of the power 2.

Comment: MO is for questions of research-level mathematics, so this question will probably be closed.  However, it seems that you have already answered this: if a logistic differential equation is defined to be one of, let's say, the form $\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dt} = k P(1 - P/N)$, then your equation is not of this form, and so is not logistic.  What more is there to say?

Comment: No, this is not logistic. (Logistic has RHS quadratic in $P$). Solution of the logistic equation is expressed in terms of exponentials, while this one requires elliptic functions.

Comment: @Yousef  Mohamed ,Logistic map is known for discrete map not continious

Comment: @zeraouliarafik This is besides the point, logistic ODE are a classical object, see *e.g.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation